# Why my find function doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, time, lodash

There is 1 object in array, which is:

```
0: {From: Wed Nov 08 2017 07:50:00}
```

and with this function using lodash I want to find if there is an object equel to date i am looking for, rounded to 10 minutes:

```
let find = _.findIndex(myArray, e => e.From == new Date(Math.floor(newDate.getTime() / 600000) * 600000));
```

The `newDate` date object has a value of `Wed Nov 08 2017 07:55:00` and the expected outcome is index `0`, instead it returns `-1` which means nothing was found.

Comment: In JS object references are only equal if they point to exactly the same object.

Comment: it is a date object

Comment: i suggest converting them to timestamps for the comparison. Another thing, "rounding" the date to 10min (floored actually) would only work if the date coming from the array is a "multiple" of 10 minutes too. I would personnally compare timestamp to an interval with `<` and `>` just in case..

Comment: i know, they are a multiple of 10 minutes, i will now compare their getTime() values, thanks for advices